# Join column name to the value in another column

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables:

Category Table

```
> ID    Code    CodeValue    Value 
> 1     sex     1            Male 
> 1     sex     2            Female 
> 2     age     1            Under 20 
> 2     age     2            Between 20 and 40 
> 2     age     3            Over 40
```

Data Table

```
> sex    age  
> 1      1
> 1      2
> 2      2
> 1      3
```

I want to return the Value of a field based on the Code, so that the final table would like something like below:

```
> sex      age  
> Male     Under 20
> Male     Between 20 and 40
> Female   Between 20 and 40
> Male     Over 40
```

Is there any way to join the values (sex age) of the 'Code' column in the Category Table with the column names in the Data table, and then return the corresponding 'Value' (Male, Female, Under 20 etc...)

Thanks!

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the table twice, once for each category.

```
SELECT cts.value sex, cta.value age
FROM data_table dt
INNER JOIN category_table cts
  ON dt.sex = cts.code_value AND cts.code = 'sex'
INNER JOIN category_table cta
  ON dt.age = cta.code_value AND cta.code = 'age'
```

Comment: your second join should be dt.age, not dt.sex

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to join without explicitly saying 'sex' and 'age'? Often tables have 15+ columns with different names, and I would rather not hard code everything. Is there any way to make use of column names using system tables?

Comment: The design of the table is such that you need to hard code. Since the code column in the first table has text values, I don't see another way of doing this.